# Auditing EntityChange conditionally based on instance value

Tags: c#, abp

Is there a way to disable auditing conditionally based on instance value?

I have a table of entities with a status column (either 0 for 'published' or 1 for 'still in editing').
Now I'd like to monitor the property changes by using Volo.Abp.Auditing, but only after publishing it.

If Status:

- 1 -> 0: Audited
- 0 -> 1: Audited
- stays at 0: Audited
- stays at 1: **DisableAuditing**

```
[Audited] // but not if Status stays at 1
public class Product : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
   public int Status { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `EntityHistoryHelper` and override `ShouldSaveEntityHistory`:

```cs
[Dependency(ServiceLifetime.Transient, ReplaceServices = true)]
public class MyEntityHistoryHelper : EntityHistoryHelper
{
    public MyEntityHistoryHelper(
        IAuditingStore auditingStore,
        IOptions<AbpAuditingOptions> options,
        IClock clock,
        IJsonSerializer jsonSerializer,
        IAuditingHelper auditingHelper)
        : base(auditingStore, options, clock, jsonSerializer, auditingHelper)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ShouldSaveEntityHistory(EntityEntry entityEntry, bool defaultValue = false)
    {
        if (!base.ShouldSaveEntityHistory(entityEntry, defaultValue))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified && entityEntry.Entity is Product)
        {
            var status = entityEntry.Property(nameof(Product.Status));
            if (status.OriginalValue.Equals(1) && status.CurrentValue.Equals(1))
            {
                // stays at 1: DisableAuditing
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```